# Converting DriverVersion to Human readable format

Tags: c++, winapi, setupapi

I have searched high and low for it, could not find any documentation, I am able to get the **DriverVersion** as described [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553287(v=vs.85).aspx). Creating and enumerating the device drives is working so there is no need to look there. The **DriverVersion** is a type of ***"DWORDLONG"***. I need to convert this to Human readable format like 20.xx.xx.xx. There ain't any documentation on MSDN, or anywhere I have searched.

Any help will be appreciated.

Example value of "*DriverVersion*" : **1688863374327808**

Code snippet, if at all its required,

```
SP_DEVINFO_DATA devInfo;
                devInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA);
                if (SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(handle, 0, &devInfo))
                {   
                    if(SetupDiBuildDriverInfoList(handle,&devInfo,SPDIT_COMPATDRIVER))
                     {
                         SP_DRVINFO_DATA drvInfo;
                        drvInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DRVINFO_DATA);
                            int i=0;
                        while(1)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                if (SetupDiEnumDriverInfo(handle, &devInfo, SPDIT_COMPATDRIVER, i++, &drvInfo))
                                {
                                    cout<<"Version :"<<drvInfo.DriverVersion<<endl; // Need Human Readable version here.
                                }
                                else
                                    break;
                            }
                            catch(std::exception ex)
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                     }
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `ULARGE_INTEGER` union, the `HIWORD`/`LOWORD` macros and string formatting utils like `boost::format` to do the following (untested code):

```
SP_DRVINFO_DATA driverInfoData;
ULARGE_INTEGER version;

version.QuadPart = driverInfoData.DriverVersion;

std::string versionStr = (boost::format("%s.%s.%s.%s")
    % HIWORD(version.HighPart)
    % LOWORD(version.HighPart)
    % HIWORD(version.LowPart)
    % LOWORD(version.LowPart)).str();
```

Following your code and to get rid of boost simply do:

```
std::cout << "Version: "
          << std::to_string(HIWORD(version.HighPart)) << "."
          << std::to_string(LOWORD(version.HighPart)) << "."
          << std::to_string(HIWORD(version.LowPart)) << "."
          << std::to_string(LOWORD(version.LowPart)) << std::endl;
```

Comment: Still didn't test it but can it not be done natively without using any other libraries like boost?

Comment: Yes, of course. There are many ways to convert the numbers into strings, e.g. `std::stringstream` or `std::to_string`: http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/D9j2Nwbp/

Comment: Awesome! Works as expected, Can you explain the logic of how those version strings are encoded to the DWORDLONG ? @Wum

Comment: `ULARGE_INTEGER` is a union that represents a 64-bit unsigned integer value. You assign `SP_DRVINFO_DATA.DriverVersion` to it which is a 64-bit unsigned integer as well. Using the macros `HIWORD`/`LOWORD` you retrieve the high-order/low-order word of the 32-bit data members `ULARGE_INTEGER.HighPart` and `ULARGE_INTEGER.LowPart` of your `ULARGE_INTEGER`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!, That helped

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's interested in the Golang implementation, here you go.

```
highPart := uint32(drvInfo.DriverVersion >> 32)
lowPart := uint32(drvInfo.DriverVersion & 0xffffffff)
versionStr := fmt.Sprintf("%d.%d.%d.%d",
    uint16(highPart>>16),
    uint16(highPart),
    uint16(lowPart>>16),
    uint16(lowPart))
fmt.Printf("Version: %s\n", versionStr)
```